# Python Requests with Django Rest Framework - 'detail': 'Authentication credentials were not provided'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, django-rest-framework-permissions

I've got a tiny function that just looks to get a response from my DRF API Endpoint.

My DRF settings look like this:

```
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        # Enabling this it will require Django Session (Including CSRF)
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        # Globally only allow IsAuthenticated users access to API Endpoints
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"
    ],
```

I'm using this to try and hit the endpoint:

```
def get_car_details(car_id):
    headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
    api_app = "http://localhost:8000/"
    api_model = "cars/"
    response = requests.get(api_app + api_model + str(car_id), headers=headers)
    json_response = response.json()
    return json_response
```

I keep getting `'detail': 'Authentication credentials were not provided'`

Do I need to generate a CSRF token and include it in a GET request? The only time this gets hit is when a user goes to a view that requires they are logged in. Is there a way to pass that logged-in user to the endpoint??

Comment: You seem to already know what you need to do. You can get the CSRF token from the headers of a request from a browser’s dev tools

Comment: I was curious if there was any other way to pass the logged in user across, because this is a get request (so CSRF shouldn't be required for get, just put, post, patch, delete). I just wasn't sure the best way to go about that.

Comment: You have IsAuthenticated as the default permission class… you can change that to AllowAny for this view if you like

Comment: So that automatically allows for authenticated users to hit the end points? Hmm. I'm wondering why I see that error then. Maybe I do need to include the CSRF with a get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make your request from the `get_car_details` function you need to be sure that the request is authenticated. This does not look like a CSRF issue.

When using session based authentication a session cookie is passed back after logging in. So before you call `get_car_details` you would need to first make a request to login, keep that session, and use that session when calling the API.

Requests has a session class `requests.Session()` that you can use for this purpose. Details here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Many people find token based authentication easier partly a session cookie does not need to be maintained.

Comment: would I have to just pass that function my `sessionid` cookie then and include it with the requests.Session() .get request?